# Detect a thin and long object in the diagonal position

Tags: python, computer-vision, counting, yolov5

I have a dataset of a single object that looks like pens and I need to count them. I thought to use object detection and object tracker. after a lot of research, I decide to use yolov5 and deep sort. after labeling the dataset and train it, it worked just fine until the big problem shows. When the "pens" stack side by side in a diagonal way the Yolo fails to detect them since the labels are too close to each other. I tried to raise the thresh hold to 0.95 and still have an issue.
I realized that in my dataset most of the labels have at least 60% overlapping which means that in most cases the label contains an object and half or more.
So the big question is How to detect an object in such a crowded scene when Yolo doesn't have the ability to label in a diagonal way?

Comment: Although your question is quite clear it might help to add images, showing a labelled image with this edge case.